# Deletion in CoreData doesn't delete; deleted object appears after relaunching

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3, ios10

My code of deletion of object from core data:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // removing from core data
        let managedContext = DataController().managedObjectContext
        managedContext.delete(books[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)
        books.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
// I debug on this step : "po books" and I do see that the book was deleted from the books. even more there is no errors.
        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
        // Delete the row from the data source (from table view)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}
```

So after deleting the book. It disappears from the table view and also it is removed from the books (core data entity).

But then I relaunch the app and the deleted book will appear again (as it was never deleted before).

I found this: [link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/38/9/how-to-delete-a-core-data-object)

But unfortunately it doesn't make much sense because of some commits etc. I'm storing on core data which is locally on device.

May be these codes may help:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let managedContext = DataController().managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Book> = Book.fetchRequest()
    do {
        let results =
            try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        books = results
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
    booksListTableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: bookCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ShowDataTableViewCell
    let index = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row
    let book = books[indexPath.row]
    cell.valueLabel.text = book.value(forKey: "bookName") as! String?
    return cell
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Be careful with default initializers like `DataController()`. You will get always a new instance of the class with a different managed context. It makes prefect sense that Apple recommends to keep the Core Data stack in AppDelegate (or at least use a singleton class).

Comment: the reason why i didn't use AppDelegate is because i added core data after project was created. found the tutorial where it was done via adding new class which is DataController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save a managed object context it saves it to its parent context. That doesn't necessarily mean it is saved to disk.

To save to disk you need to save the persistent store. If you create a new application in Xcode and choose "Use Core Data" you will see code in the app delegate that does this in `applicationWillTerminate`.

Comment: that's the issue that i added core data after creating the project. manually. not at the creation moment. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per suggestions above I modified AppDelegate so that it is the same as in the project where I would add core data. 
And it works good now.

Thanks!